# Use neo4j with R

Tags: r, graph, neo4j, bulbs

Is there a R library that supports neo4j? I would like to construct a R graph (e.g. igraph) from neo4j or - vice versa - store a R graph in neo4j.

More precisely, I am looking for something similar to [bulbflow](http://bulbflow.com/overview/) for Python.

---

**Update**

There is a new neo4j driver for R that looks promising: http://nicolewhite.github.io/RNeo4j/. I changed the correct answer.

Comment: Since neo4j has a [REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.6/rest-api.html), 
you should be able to connect to it by hand, 
with the `RJSONIO` package to handle JSON data
and `RCurl` to send the queries.

Comment: A direct access via REST is possible of course, thanks for RJSONIO. What I am looking for is a more convenient R binding for neo4j. something like: "g <- graph.neo4j(), g.addNode(x), g.addEdge(from, to)" .

Comment: Also, you probably could import and export GraphML?, See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/gremlin-plugin.html#rest-api-load-a-sample-graph for loading, exporting is similar.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any R libraries. May be this will be helpful to look at [Neo4j-Cypher-R Example Code](https://gist.github.com/1178110)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the RNeo4j driver. The function shown above is incomplete: it cannot return single column data and there is no NULL handling.

https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j

Comment: Very nice, I'll have a look!

Answer (score 13):

This [link](https://gist.github.com/1178110) might be helpful. I'm going to connect ne04j with R in the following days and will try first with the provided link. Hope it helps.

I tried it out and it works well. Here is the function that works:
First, install and load packages and then execute function:

```
install.packages('RCurl')
install.packages('RJSONIO')

library('bitops')
library('RCurl')
library('RJSONIO')

query <- function(querystring) {
  h = basicTextGatherer()
  curlPerform(url="localhost:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query",
    postfields=paste('query',curlEscape(querystring), sep='='),
    writefunction = h$update,
    verbose = FALSE
  )           
  result <- fromJSON(h$value())
  #print(result)
  data <- data.frame(t(sapply(result$data, unlist)))
  print(data)
  names(data) <- result$columns

}
```

and this is an example of calling function:

```
q <-"start a = node(50) match a-->b RETURN b"
 data <- query(q)
```

Comment: Good to know that I'm not alone in this ;) Would be interesting to know why you're working on this and how you use neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the R script (thanks a lot for providing it) and it seems to me that you can directly use :
**/db/data/cypher**
instead of 
**db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query**
(with neo4j 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it fits your requirements but have a look at Gephi.
http://gephi.org/.

Comment: This does not really relate to my question ... I am looking for a R package that allows easy access to neo4j. Gephi is nice though :)

Comment: I use Gephi as an intermediate to neo.  There's a good plugin if you export igraph to GEXF, then import that to gephi.  Then you can export to neo4j.  It's a little circuitous, but easy in a point-and-click kind of way.