# Parsing vectors from R into cypher query via RCurl with NEO4J's REST API

Tags: r, rest, curl, neo4j

I'm trying to send queries from my R session to neo4j

Looking at the REST API docs provided by neo4j: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html I've formulated a successful curl query below

```
curl -X POST -d @test.json http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

where the contents of test.json are as follows

```
{"query": "start pathway=node:pathwayid(pathway={pathway}) match pathway--(ko:`ko`)<-[r]-(cpd:`cpd`) return ko.ko,r,cpd.cpd limit 5;","params": {"pathway":"path:ko00010"} }
```

Solutions given so far on SO in [Use neo4j with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188918/use-neo4j-with-r) where 
the query is stored in querystring (see code below) do not utilise ability to parameterise the cypher query. eg:

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)

h = basicTextGatherer()

  curlPerform(url="localhost:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query",
postfields=paste('query',curlEscape(querystring), sep='='),
writefunction = h$update,
verbose = FALSE
)           
result <- fromJSON(h$value())
```

in this case querystring is:

```
start pathway=node:pathwayid('pathway:"path:ko00010"') match pathway--(ko:`ko`)<-[r]-(cpd:`cpd`) return ko.ko,r,cpd.cpd limit 5;
```

I'm curious how do i parse parameters into the RCurl.

Comment: I'm guessing I'll have to change this portion of the r code `postfields=paste('query',curlEscape(querystring), sep='=')`

Answer (score 0):

Used this instead

```
fromJSON(
getURL("http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher", 
    customrequest='POST', 
    httpheader=c('Content- Type'='application/json'),
    postfields=toJSON(list(query=q2,params=list(pathway=q3)))
  )
)
```

code modified from :
http://pastebin.com/FAeJ0b2R